# seedファイルからデータベースへデータを投入することができない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

**やりたいこと**
seedファイルからテーブルへデータを投入したい

**起きている問題やエラーメッセージ**
rails db:seedを行ってもデータの投入ができない
rails cでcreateを実行し中身を確認してみましたが、投入できておりませんでした。

```
[2] pry(main)> Product.create(id: 1,product_name: '海鮮鍋セット(4人前)', product_price: '12800', image: File.open('./app/assets/images/uni.jpg'))
=> #<Product:0x00007f87f1b26008 id: 1, product_price: 12800, product_name: "海鮮鍋セット(4人前)", image: "#<File:0x00007f87f1b260a8>", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[3] pry(main)> Product.all
  Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`
=> []
```

**関連するソースコード**

seeds.rb

```
Product.create(id: 1,product_name: '海鮮鍋セット(4人前)', product_price: '12800', image: File.open('./app/assets/images/uni.jpg'))
Product.create(id: 2, product_name: 'もつ鍋セット(4人前)', product_price: '10800', image: File.open('./app/assets/images/motu.jpg'))
```

20210828062853_create_products.rb

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.integer :product_price
      t.string :product_name
      t.text :image 
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_08_28_062853) do

  create_table "menus", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date "arrival", null: false
    t.integer "number", null: false
    t.integer "product_name", null: false
    t.integer "product_price", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "product_id", null: false
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_orders_on_product_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "products", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "product_price"
    t.string "product_name"
    t.text "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "reservations", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time "time", null: false
    t.date "date", null: false
    t.integer "people", null: false
    t.text "remark"
    t.integer "person_price", null: false
    t.integer "total_price", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "menu_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["menu_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_menu_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reservations_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "nickname", null: false
    t.string "phone", null: false
    t.string "postal_code", null: false
    t.string "prefecture", null: false
    t.string "municipality", null: false
    t.string "address", null: false
    t.string "building"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "orders", "users"
  add_foreign_key "reservations", "users"
end
```

**試したこと**

```
created_at: nil, updated_at: nil
```

と出ておりましたので、ターミナルで全ての情報を記述したものを実行しましたが、投入するに至りませんでした。

```
[4] pry(main)> Product.create(id: 1, product_name: '海鮮鍋セット(4人前)', product_price: '12800', image: File.open('./app/assets/images/uni.jpg'), created_at: 'Sat, 28 Aug 2021 07:14:56 UTC +00:00', updated_at: 'Sat, 28 Aug 2021 07:14:56 UTC +00:00')
=> #<Product:0x00007f881231f5c8
 id: 1,
 product_price: 12800,
 product_name: "海鮮鍋セット(4人前)",
 image: "#<File:0x00007f881231f6e0>",
 created_at: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 07:14:56 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sat, 28 Aug 2021 07:14:56 UTC +00:00>
```

↓

```
[5] pry(main)> Product.all
  Product Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`
=> []
```

**使用言語・ライブラリのバージョン**
Rails 6.0.4.1

このほか、何か投入できていない原因をご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: Product.create! で例外発生させてみるといかがでしょう

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは！
Rails初学者ですが、お役に立てればと思いコメントさせて頂きます！

まず、`rails db:seed`を実行した際にサンプルデータが投入できないということだと思いますが、`rails db:seed`実行時にエラーは何か出ていませんでしょうか？

ちなみにidやcreated_at・updated_atはrails側で勝手に振ってくれますので決め打ちはよくないようです。

自分がysk0507さんのseed.rbを書いたとしたらこんな感じにすると思います。

```
Product.create!(product_name: '海鮮鍋セット(4人前)', product_price: '12800', image: open(Rails.root.join('/app/assets/images/uni.jpg'))
```

※createの後に `!` をつけるとエラーが起きて保存できなかった時に例外を出してメッセージを出してくれます。

後はエラー文を見て原因を特定するのが良いかと思いますがいかがでしょうか！

Comment: @shumpei様


ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
無事に解決することができました。
解決内容について以下に記述いたします。

```!```を追加することによりエラーメッセージの確認をすることができました。

今回の原因としましては、productsテーブルとordersテーブルでアソシエーションを組んでいるにも関わらず、productsテーブルにorder_idのカラムを作っていないことが保存できていない原因となっておりました。

order_idを追加し、モデルへ以下内容を追記することで無事にseedファイルよりデータの投入を行うことができました。

models/product.rb
```belongs_to :order, optional: true```


エラーメッセージを表示させるということをご教示いただたおかげで解決するに至りました。

大変ありがとうございます。